# Change Gnu Make -j Behavior to personally ignore, but pass on?

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile that is a 3rdParty dependency builder, so it's actually just going to various other directories and running cmake/make with various flags to ensure all 15-20 dependencies of my project compile the way I need.

Building parallel would *really* help here, (the build takes about 2 hours serially), but I need a 'make -jN' to not run the toplevel makefile parallel, instead run it serially (the various 3rdParty libs have internal dependencies to meet) and pass the arg to the inside makefiles.

Is there a way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.NOTPARALLEL` pseudo target; from the docs:

> `.NOTPARALLEL'
>
> > ```
> > If `.NOTPARALLEL' is mentioned as a target, then this invocation of
> > `make' will be run serially, even if the `-j' option is given.
> > Any recursively invoked `make' command will still be run in
> > parallel (unless its makefile contains this target).  Any
> > prerequisites on this target are ignored.
> > ```